# Rails Form with has_many through - Which model to choose?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have the following models:

```
Student has_many :subjects, :through => :classes

Subject has_many :students, :through => :classes

Class belongs_to :subject
      belongs_to :student
```

The model class has an extra attribute (among the foreign keys to subject and students table) called level.

Basically I want to be able to have a form that will let the student to choose a subject and relate that subject to its record.  So, I have this:

```
ClassesController < ApplicationController

def new
 @list_of_subjects = Subject.all
 # What should I do here?
end
```

My question is: How should I create the object for the form? From which model it should be, subject, student or class? I want to be able to create a record in the class table that would relate the student and the subject that the student has chosen, but I don't know if I am doing it wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think you could create a model called `Class` since it's a keyword, but that's neither here nor there...

First I think your controller and view should be using `Student` since it's the student that's selecting these things. Next, I think what you want to do is to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :class` in your `Student` model which allows you to create an instance of the `Class` connector model from `Student`.

What you're trying to do sounds a little like something I tried to do. I have my full code there.

[Using nested attributes to easily select associations in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282543/using-nested-attributes-to-easily-select-associations-in-a-form)

I later refined it a bit in this question too to make the code less hideous:

[Rails: How do I prepend or insert an association with build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599519/rails-how-do-i-prepend-or-insert-an-association-with-build)

I know it's late, but I hope that helps.