# Best way to handle multiple associated models in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, models, model-associations

I have a fairly simple setup:

**models/person.rb**

```
has_many :links
```

**models/link_category.rb**

```
attr_accessible :title
has_many :links
```

**models/links.rb**

```
attr_accessible :person_id, :link_category_id, :url
belongs_to :person
belongs_to :link_category
```

Example of link categories might be things like "facebook, twitter, pinterest, wordpress, blog, etc."

What I want to create, as DRY and RESTful as possible, is a single page that lists all of the link categories and a text field for them to either enter (or update if already provided) the urls for each category.

For example, something like this `http://example.com/person/23/links/edit` might show a form like this:

Facebook: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

Twitter:  __ http://twitter.com/example ***_*_**

Wordpress: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

Pinterest: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

I'm wondering if anyone has an elegant way of doing this as it's become pretty common in a number of web sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is very similar to something I once asked for:

[Rails: How do I prepend or insert an association with build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599519/rails-how-do-i-prepend-or-insert-an-association-with-build)

You can call a function like that in your controller or maybe an `:after_initialize`.

To take advantage of it, you would need to add `has_many :link_categories, through: :links` to your `Person` model.